# Create nested directories in OneDriveForBusiness using GraphServiceClient

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I have been trying to leverage the Microsoft Graph Api to communicate with user's one drive business inside a MVC web app, have set up everything with delegated permissions and can read and write data in logged-in user's ODB fine however is there any way by which nested folder or directory structure can be created?

Currently I am using code below to create the folder in the root of user's ODB and works fine but looking for a way to create hierarchy of the folders when path is provided before uploading the file in it.

```
 DriveItem rootDirectory = graphServiceClient.Me.Drive.Root.Children.Request().AddAsync(new DriveItem
            {
                Name = "RootDirectory",
                Folder = new Folder(),
            }).Result;
```

And for another folder inside RootDirectory trying this but does not seem to work (where rootDirectory is object created above)

```
 DriveItem subDirectory = graphServiceClient.Me.Drive.Root.Children.Request().AddAsync(new DriveItem
            {
                Name = "SubDirectory",
                Folder = rootDirectory.Folder
            }).Result;
```

Even if it works with some fix, not sure if it is most optimal way to do it, suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I made a small function to do that.

While it is true that the use of try-catch is not the best practice, in the end I think it is better than polling each folder recursively for its children, then lookup by name if part of the path is there.

```
public async Task CreateFolder(string foldername)
{
  string[] splitted = foldername.Split(new string[] { "/" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
  var f = graphServiceClient.Me.Drive.Root;
  string p = "";
  IDriveItemRequestBuilder b;
  DriveItem driveItem;
  foreach (string folder in splitted)
  {
    p = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", p, string.IsNullOrEmpty(p) ? "" : "/", folder);

    b = graphServiceClient.Me.Drive.Root.ItemWithPath(p);
    try
    {
      driveItem = await b.Request().GetAsync();
    }
    catch
    {
      driveItem = null;
    }
    if (driveItem == null)
    {
      var f2 = await f.Children.Request().AddAsync(new DriveItem()
      {
        Name = folder,
        Folder = new Folder()
      });

      b = graphServiceClient.Me.Drive.Root.ItemWithPath(p);
    }
    f = b;
  }
}
```

and you call is like this:

```
await CreateFolder("folder1/folder2/folder3");
```

Answer (score 2):

> but looking for a way to create hierarchy of the folders when path is provided before uploading the file in it.

Based on my experience `hierarchy of the folders` is not supported by graphServiceClient currently.

If want to create a sub folder, it requires that parent folder is exist.

As a workaround, we could create the sub folder with following code. You also create a 
**recursive** function to create the nested function

```
var folder= graphserviceClient.Me.Drive.Root.Children.Request()
            .AddAsync(new DriveItem
            {
                Name = "tomfolder",
                Folder = new Folder()
            }).Result;

var subfolder = graphserviceClient.Me.Drive.Items[folder.Id].Children.Request()
                .AddAsync(new DriveItem 
                {
                  Name = "subfolder",
                  Folder = new Folder()}
                ).Result;
```

And you also could [give your good ideas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_post_children#comments-container) to azure team.

Answer (score 0):

I revisited the answer of Pic Mickael because it doesn't work for me (it just create two subfolders).

What I do is to create the first folder of my path so I have a start folder.
If I don't do this, when I try to add the drive item with an empty  path I get an error.

So, let's create a root folder, first:

```
    private static void CreateRootFolder(GraphServiceClient gc, string rootFolder)
    {
        var root = gc
            .Drives[_driveId]
            .Root
            .Children
            .Request()
            .AddAsync(new DriveItem()
            {
                Name = rootFolder,
                Folder = new Microsoft.Graph.Folder(),
                AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    {
                        "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior", "replace"
                    }
                }
            })
            .Result;
    }
```

When I have my first folder, I can loop through all the others:

```
   private static void CreateSubFolders(GraphServiceClient gc, string rootFolder, string foldername)
    {
        string[] splitted = foldername.Split(new string[] { "/" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string pathCompleto = rootFolder;
        
        foreach (string folder in splitted)
        {
            var driveItem = new DriveItem
            {
                Name = folder,
                Folder = new Microsoft.Graph.Folder(),
                AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    {
                        "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior", "replace"
                    }
                }
            };

            var newFolder = gc
                .Drives[_driveId]
                .Root
                .ItemWithPath(pathCompleto)
                .Children
                .Request()
                .AddAsync(driveItem)
                .Result;

            pathCompleto = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", pathCompleto, string.IsNullOrEmpty(pathCompleto) ? "" : "/", folder);
        }
```

In the main program I will have two calls like this:

```
CreateRootFolder(_graphClient, "Folder00");
CreateSubFolders(_graphClient, "Folder00", "FolderAA/FolderBB/FolderCC/FolderDD/FolderEE");
```

This could be improved, but in my case it nicely resolve the problem.